# How do I target every other figure tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm a little stuck on this one...  I have 4 figures and 2 Divs within the parent article.  There is an img and figcaption within each of the 4 figures.  I'd like to alternate the position of the img and figcaption for every other figure.

The CSS that I'm using is working.  Somewhat...  The part that has me confused is that the two divs I am using for the H1 seem to be being counted as children that are equal to the figures.  I'm trying to target the figures that are children of the parent article.  When using `#team article figure:nth-child(even){direction: rtl;}` I thought the result would make the second rectangle in my example place the image on the right but it doesn't.  If I take the Divs away everything works fine.

How can I get around this?  I'm not very experienced with selecting child etc...

https://jsfiddle.net/iBrad/hmjc0sad/28/

```css
html {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {margin:0;padding:0;}

#team {width:100%;}
article {
    max-width: 1100px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 100px 34px;
    margin: 0;
}
#team article figure {border:2px solid #eee;}
#team article figure:nth-child(even),#team article figure:nth-child(even) h3 {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}
#team article figure:nth-child(even) p {
    text-align: right;
}

#team figure img {
    width:230px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#team figcaption {
    width: 55%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:10px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: "Raleway",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: .02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f00000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<section id="team">
    <article>
  
        <div style="text-align:center;"><img style="width: 50px;vertical-align: top;margin: 0 20px 0 0;" src="https://heritagegis.ca/crma/images/fav.png"> <h1 style="display: inline-block;margin:0;">THE TEAM</h1></div>
        
        <figure><img src="https://heritagegis.ca/crma/images/vt_007.png" alt="nathan.jpg"><figcaption><h3>Person's Name</h3><p>Totally awesome description about this super guy/gal.  They are so super that I wrote this special paragraph just for them and only them!  Don't tell the person below otherwise they may feel left out!  This is so much better than Ipsum or that other guy Lorum.  Who are they anyway?  And who taught them to write?  Can't understand a single word they write.  Sheesh!</p></figcaption></figure>
        <figure><img src="https://heritagegis.ca/crma/images/vt_007.png" alt="nathan.jpg"><figcaption><h3>Person's Name</h3><p>Totally awesome description about this super guy/gal.  They are so super that I wrote this special paragraph just for them and only them!  Don't tell the person below otherwise they may feel left out!  This is so much better than Ipsum or that other guy Lorum.  Who are they anyway?  And who taught them to write?  Can't understand a single word they write.  Sheesh!</p></figcaption></figure>
        
        <div style="text-align:center;"><img style="width: 50px;vertical-align: top;margin: 0 20px 0 0;" src="https://heritagegis.ca/crma/images/fav.png"><h1 style="display: inline-block;margin:0;">THE BOARD</h1></div>
        
        <figure><img src="https://heritagegis.ca/crma/images/vt_007.png" alt="nathan.jpg"><figcaption><h3>Person's Name</h3><p>Totally awesome description about this super guy/gal.  They are so super that I wrote this special paragraph just for them and only them!  Don't tell the person below otherwise they may feel left out!  This is so much better than Ipsum or that other guy Lorum.  Who are they anyway?  And who taught them to write?  Can't understand a single word they write.  Sheesh!</p></figcaption></figure>
        <figure><img src="https://heritagegis.ca/crma/images/vt_007.png" alt="nathan.jpg"><figcaption><h3>Person's Name</h3><p>Totally awesome description about this super guy/gal.  They are so super that I wrote this special paragraph just for them and only them!  Don't tell the person below otherwise they may feel left out!  This is so much better than Ipsum or that other guy Lorum.  Who are they anyway?  And who taught them to write?  Can't understand a single word they write.  Sheesh!</p></figcaption></figure>
    
    </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: nth-of-type instead of nth-child

Comment: @DCR - I'm trying to avoid js but thanks!

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Will try that, thanks!  If I'm still stuck, can you re-open my question?